# PHPUnit testing code that uses globals. (Was: Supplied argument is not a valid sdl resource)

Tags: php, unit-testing, soap, wsdl, phpunit

I am writing a Unit Test for a PHP library that uses SOAP. The test case has **two** tests in it.

The library is falling over on the **second** unit test with the following message (I am using PHPUnit):

```
SoapClient::__call(): supplied argument is not a valid sdl resource

/test/SOAPLib.php:186
/test/SOAPLibTest.php:56
```

Line 186 of the library I am testing is:

```
$issue = $client->getIssueById($auth_token, $id);
```

This does not fail when called in the usual fashion from any other script - It is only failing when used from the **second** unit test. This implies that there is some kind of authentication or token error with the global variables in my second SOAP call.

Line 56 of the UnitTest file is:

```
list($summary, $pri) = \SOAPLibTest\get_issue_by_id($id);
```

I have looked up SoapClient::_*call(): in the PHP manual, which says that function is deprecated, and I should be using SoapClient::*_soapCall instead. The problem is that I don't know how to change it to that.

Attempting to update php-soap reports that I am already up-to-date.

I really am stumped on this one, and there doesn't appear to be any immediate help from Google.

Many thanks,
**ns**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the root of the problem - It was actually a PHPUnit problem with some global variables I had in my SOAP library. I will change the title of this question to reflect PHPUnit, not php-soap as I originally thought.

This blog post by Sebastian Bergmann (The creator of PHPUnit) was really helpful:

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/797-Global-Variables-and-PHPUnit.html

Some important statements he included were:

> It is hard to test code that uses singletons. The same is true for code that uses global variables."
>
> Typically, the code you want to test is coupled strongly with a global variable and you cannot control its creation. An additional problem is the fact that one test's change to a global variable might break another test.
>
> The implementation of the backup and restore operations for the global and super-global variables uses serialize() and unserialize(). Objects of some classes that are provided by PHP itself, such as PDO, cannot be serialized and the backup operation will break when such an object is stored in the $GLOBALS array, for instance.
>
> The backup and restore operations for the global and super-global variables can be disabled like this:

```
<?php
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $backupGlobals = FALSE;

    // ...
}
?>
```

I hope this helps some other people.

Regards,
**ns**